# How to use client certificate in @apollo/datasource-rest

Tags: node.js, apollo-server, apollo-datasource-rest

I am using subclass of `@apollo/datasource-rest` for fetching data from REST API's in my project. I need to add a client certificate in every request in made in my subclass. I know that It is possible to add certificate in the https `https.Agent` and it can used in the previous version of apollo datasource rest `apollo-datasource-rest` like this

```
this.get(<reqparams> , {agent : <https agent with certificate>})
```

Not sure how to use the same with new version of apollo datasouce (`@apollo/datasource-rest`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a custom agent, you need to pass a custom `fetch` to `RESTDataSource`.  The lack of support for agent is explicitly called out in the [FetcherRequestInit type](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-utils/blob/2bcca09b7c0b40845bc0c4d08e86bc7f498cc211/packages/fetcher/src/index.ts#L43-L44):

```
  // We explicitly do not support non-portable options like `node-fetch`'s
  // `agent`.
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! Based on it, I was able to find a solution and posted it separately as answer, giving credit to your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by overriding the default node-fetch in RESTDataSource

eg :

```
import https from 'https';
import nodeFetch from 'node-fetch';


class MyAPI extends RESTDataSource {
    constructor() {
        super({
            fetch: (url, init) => nodeFetch(url, {
                ...init,
                agent: new https.Agent({

                    keepAlive: true,
                    pfx: < My PFX > ,
                    passphrase: < Passphrase > ,
                })
            })
        });
    }
}
```